# How to detect if url is segment or parameter on Angular

Tags: angular

Hello I have problem on url routes.

here is app-routing path examples

```
{ path: ':lang/:id', component: ClientPageComponent, canActivate: [ClientGuardService] },
{ path: ':lang/product', component: SearchPageComponent, canDeactivate: [ClientGuardService] }
```

I want to detect if path includes `id` load `ClientPageComponent` but if segment is not `id` I want to load `SearchPageComponent` here is basic `[ClientGuardService]`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ClientGuardService implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        if (isNaN(route.params.id)) {
            return false
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the `id` parameter from `url` and check if it exists. Code will look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ClientGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        let id = route.params['id'];
        if (id){
           return true;
        } else {
           this.router.navigate(['/lang/product']);
           return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was only one problem, I had to switch lines end even `canActivate` guard was not needed

```
{ path: ':lang/product', component: SearchPageComponent },    
{ path: ':lang/:id', component: ClientPageComponent }
```